# Binding to the Current Item (WPF)

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I am attempting to bind a `ListView` control to a `DataTable`, but the WPF binding system seems to be complaining about the binding path I specify.

As an example, a `GridViewColumn` is defined as follows:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ColumnTitle" 
 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=/, 
                        Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

As far as I understand (and MSN seems to support me), specifying `Path=/` should make the binding on the current item of the data collection.

The error I receive (in the trace window) is:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: ''
>   property not found on 'current item of collection' ''OrdersRow'
>   (HashCode=680171)'. BindingExpression:Path=/; DataItem='OrdersRow'
>   (HashCode=680171); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')

This is giving me the impression that `/` isn't even a valid path, and WPF is expecting something after the slash. If so, how else would I bind to the current item? Why am I getting this error in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion is that the DataContext for the GridViewColumn is *not* the top collection, but is already the item that is bound to that column, so you don't need to specify a path.

The time that the you may use a path like this is if your control's DataContext is a List and you want to bind to the selected item. A possible example would be.

```
<Combobox DataContext={Binding ColourList}
          DataSource={Binding} <!--Bind to the datacontext -->
          ForeColor={Binding/} <!--Bind to the currently selected item 
                                   in the datacontext -->
          />
```

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, that's exactly where my confusion came from. I didn't even try leaving the path out becase I automatically thought this referred to the collection as a whole. Thanks for the full explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried omitting the Path parameter?

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ColumnTitle"
     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Thanks for your reply. You are indeed correct about missing out the `Path` parameter. Sorry, but I had to give Martin the answer for the extra detail.