# TreeView with DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I want to create a databinding on a TreeView with the following model:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = model;
    }
    ...
}

public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private IList<Document> sourceDocuments;

    public IList<Document> SourceDocuments
    {
        get { return sourceDocuments; }
        set
        {
            sourceDocuments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SourceDocuments");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SourceDocuments = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public String Filename;
    public IList<DocumentBlock> Blocks { get; set; }

    public Document(String filename)
    {
        this.Filename = filename;
        Blocks = new List<DocumentBlock>();
    }
}

public class DocumentBlock
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public DocumentBlock(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And this XAML

```
 <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,6" Name="SourceDocumentsList" Width="202" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding SourceDocuments}">
     <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding /Blocks}">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding /Name}" />
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

I get the error message `'Blocks' property not found on 'current item of collection' ''Document'`. Why is this?

Comment: Is the error here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138471/binding-to-the-current-item-wpf] is related to what you're seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should drop the `/`, the `DataContext` in the `ItemTemplate` is an item, it has no current item itself. Also the `Name` binding won't work, as the `DataContext` is still a `Document`, you can specify the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate`, there the `DataContext` is a `DocumentBlock` from the `Blocks`.

You usually use `/` for a details view *outside of the TreeView*, e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceDocuments/Blocks[0].Name}"/>`