# Binding to current item in list

Tags: wpf, data-binding

So I have this xaml here

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <gameManagement:FeedGame DataContext="{Binding}" Package="{Binding Path=/}"></gameManagement:FeedGame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And a UserControl that has a `DependencyProperty` called `Package`

What I'm trying to do is to just set that property to the current item from the list. I've been at this for about an hour now, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The current code I have above tosses a `FirstChanceException` of

```
BindingExpression path error: '' property not found on 'current item of collection' ''FeedGame' (Name='Me')'. BindingExpression:Path=/; DataItem='FeedGame' (Name='Me'); target element is 'FeedGame' (Name='Me'); target property is 'Package' (type 'IPackage')
```

And if you're curious what `Me` is, this is in the xaml for the UserControl the above list box is contained in

```
x:Name="Me"
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Me}"
```

This is in `FeedGame`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PackageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Package", typeof(IPackage), typeof(FeedGame));

public IPackage Package {
    get
    {
        return (IPackage)this.GetValue(PackageProperty);
        //return this.package;
    }
    set
    {
        // Setter here never gets called.
        if (Equals(value, (IPackage)this.GetValue(PackageProperty)))
        {
            return;
        }
        SetValue(PackageProperty,value);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Package");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think is should be ` <gameManagement:FeedGame Package="{Binding}" />`

Comment: Actually I thought that also, but I guess `{Binding}` refers to the whole collection.

Comment: No, it will be the Package, because you are in the `ItemTemplate` which will be the individual items from the list.

Comment: Hm. I got the info about the `/` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138471/binding-to-the-current-item-wpf#answer-1138527 . Doing what you said doesn't help though, as the setter for `Package` never gets called.

Comment: Oh shoot, that says current selected item, not current iterative item. Either way, I'm still not getting any results :\.

Comment: what error do you get after removing the `/` ? and is Package a dependancyProperty or a standard property, Can you show the `FeedGame` code behind(relevant parts)

Comment: I don't get any error. It also still doesn't call the setter for `Package`. Maybe it would help if I posted the Package piece.

Comment: Ohhh.. The setter wont get called :), The WPF binding engine calls GetValue and SetValue directly (bypassing the property setters and getters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter wont get called when you populate Package because the binding engine calls `GetValue` and `SetValue` directly (bypassing the property Set and Get).

If you need to do some in logic in the setter and you are using binding you can use the `PropertyChangedCallback`

Example:

```
     public static readonly DependencyProperty PackageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     "Package", typeof(IPackage), typeof(FeedGame), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPackageChanged)));

     // callback when value changed
     private static void OnPackageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (Equals(e.OldValue, e.NewValue))
         {
             return;
         }
     }

     public IPackage Package
     {
         get { return (IPackage)this.GetValue(PackageProperty); }
         set { SetValue(PackageProperty, value); }
     }
```

## Edit:

### My Test

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="199" Width="191" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}"> 
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <local:FeedGame Package="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication10
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Packages.Add(new Package());
            Packages.Add(new Package());
            Packages.Add(new Package());
        }

        private ObservableCollection<IPackage> _packages = new ObservableCollection<IPackage>();
        public ObservableCollection<IPackage> Packages
        {
            get { return _packages; }
            set { _packages = value; }
        }
    }

    public class FeedGame : FrameworkElement
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PackageProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register( "Package", typeof(IPackage), typeof(FeedGame)
            , new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPackageChanged)));

         private static void OnPackageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             if (Equals(e.OldValue, e.NewValue))
             {
                 return;
             }
         }

         public IPackage Package
         {
             get { return (IPackage)this.GetValue(PackageProperty); }
             set { SetValue(PackageProperty, value); }
         }
    }

    public interface IPackage { }

    public class Package : IPackage { }
}
```

Comment: Actually that still doesn't help. OnPackageChanged never gets call either. My list ends up with two items in it though, so I know the data source is spitting out data.

Comment: hmmm.. I made a quick example and it worked ok, do you want me to post that here?

Comment: Actually, I could push my changes. I'm working on an open source app on github if you wouldn't mind taking a peek? Might be easier to spot the issue in context.

Comment: If not an example would be fine.

Comment: @kelton52, I added my test, if you add a break point on `OnPackageChanged` you will see it gets called.

Comment: Yeah I studied that crap out of that, still not working. If I call Package = whatever inside my code, it works fine, but from a the xaml it doesn't fire.

Comment: So I figured it out. The GameFeed control set the DataContext of the entire control to itself, which must have nullified the other data context from the parent control.